# ¿Como validar un usuario por su usuario o correo electronico en una consulta SQL?

Tags: php, mysql, select

Estoy realizando un sistema de login para mi aplicacion web, puedo ingresar los datos de un usuario en mi base de datos en myslq, donde guardo su: usuario, password, su correo , el problema es que quiero que el usuario pueda acceder a su cuenta con su usuario o su correo electronico, he realizado mi consulta pero solo puedo acceder por su usuario pero no por su correo. agrego parte de mi codigo para que me puedan ayudar, Gracias !

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error()); // Connect to database server(localhost) with username and password.
mysql_select_db("Datos") or die(mysql_error()); // Select registration database.

if(isset($_POST['usuario']) && !empty($_POST['usuario']) AND isset($_POST['password']) && !empty($_POST['password']))
{
    $username = mysql_escape_string($_POST['usuario']);
    $pass = mysql_escape_string(md5($_POST['password']));
                 
   $search = mysql_query("SELECT id_usuarios,usuario,email,password, active FROM usuarios WHERE  usuario='".$username."'or email='".$username."' AND password='".$pass."' AND active='1'") or die(mysql_error()); 
   $match  = mysql_num_rows($search);

    if($match > 0)
    {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['usuario']=$username;
        header('Location: welcome.php');
    }
    else
    {
        //$msg = 'Login Failed! Please make sure that you enter the correct details and that you have activated your account.';         
        header('Location: index.php');
    }
}
```

?>

Comment: La consulta tiene buena pinta, ¿da algún error?. Envíanos el dataset que usas a ver qué puede estar pasando. Y, muy importante, plantéate utilizar consultas preparadas y cambiar a `mysqli` que, con `mysql_escape_string`, no es suficiente...

Comment: Saludos. Prueba agrupando con paréntesis la parte del WHERE usurario OR email; es decir: (usuario='".$username."'or email='".$username."') desde luego; también corrobora en la BD este bien el correo o lo ingresas correctamente (por ejemplo sin espacio).

Comment: ¿Cómo estás guardando la contraseña en base de datos, texto plano o codificada?